# Google cuts off site content shown/hidden with toggle-content

Tags: seo, google, search-results

I have this pretty simple website that has all the real content hidden and then shown when users click different `href #` links. It's very weird that Google cuts off some of the content, I'm searching for groups of words from the "about us" and the beginning is found, but the end isn't.

Here's a snapshot to explain better, the content is no longer indexed in Google after the red line, yet the Facebook comments are found:

[image]

Here are the searches:

```
https://www.google.ro/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=L6rvVJDfLaGuygOcpYDIBQ#q=site:piratefm.ro+principal+a+fost+cel+de+Dubstep

https://www.google.ro/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=RKnvVKjmFIv8ywOL8IK4Dg#q=site:piratefm.ro+muzica+de+calitate+superioara
```

The site is now almost one and half years old and the content wasn't changed in a couple of months, so I don't really understand why this is happening, but I'd like it fixed so my keywords actually show up in the site, and not only in the meta tags.

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="toggle-content text-center" id="tab1">
        <h3>Despre noi</h3>
        PirateFM Romania este un proiect infiintat in 2014 cu scopul de a imprastia muzica in urechile tuturor. Canalul principal a fost cel de Dubstep, dar dupa putin timp a fost deschis si PirateFM Rap de dragul ascultatorilor de muzica Rap si Hip-Hop, iar mai apoi PirateFM Dub. Difuzam muzica de calitate superioara prin intermediul internetului non stop, la cererea ascultatorilor, asigurandu-ne ca muzica este pe placul tuturor. Aici poti asculta melodiile tale preferate in orice moment al zilei, de pe orice platforma, fie ea desktop sau mobila. Suntem mereu dispusi sa promovam producatorii in dezvoltare.
        <div class="hidemob"><br><br><h4>Spune-ne parerea ta!</h4>
        <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://facebook.com/piratefmro" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div> </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /.col-md-12 -->
```

Comment: Can you add a snapshot of the results returned by Google, and how you got that so it's clearer to users here? Also, you should note that only certain [lengths](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=description+length+is%3Aquestion) of descriptions and content are shown in SERP.

Comment: Google doesn't show your entire page, just the part it's system deems relevant.

Comment: I visited your site. I like what you have done! I also looked at your code. From an SEO standpoint, you are making some fundamental mistakes. I have similar answers to this one, but this should help you get started: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74313/improve-google-ranking-for-general-vs-specific-keywords/74334#74334

Comment: @dan I've fixed my content by the bing tool yesterday, results may still not be in google. My description and everything was messed up.

Comment: @DanielF I'd only like it to show the sentence or part of it under the link when it finds the keywords. It finds most of them but still only shows the first thing it finds on the site, aka the news box and from now on (hopefully) the description

Comment: @closetnoc thanks for the review. I'm very new to this whole SEO thing and I'm doing my best at reading docs but you just can't learn everything at once. If you could please send me an e-mail to contact@piratefm.ro with all the SEO suggestions you have regarding my code, it would be very much appreciated. Also I don't know how to properly mention several people in one comment so yeah, please tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google recently re-confirmed](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-hidden-tab-content-seo-19489.html) that they may discount content that is not immediately viewable to the user without having to do another action. Such as in a scroll box, tabbed boxes, drop down menus and the like.

I think you are seeing this here if you say you content is hidden untill you click a hash link.

Google still knows the content is on the page as it is returning your page, but it's not showing the actual search terms as highlighted as it knows they aren't immediately visible.

If you want your content to perform better (and perhaps get more traffic) and get highlighted in the Search result pages consider making the content visible on the page.

Comment: In principle, I like the idea of being able to toggle off and on content, however, it is bad from a search perspective. In a way, that is a shame. There should be a good way to satisfy both concerns. Good answer!

Comment: First of all thanks for editing out my post, I've yet to learn how to properly post images and stuff. This answer is pretty weird, since while searching I only found that invisible content is still being read, but I didn't find anything else about relevance. I can't make all the content visible because that would defeat the idea of the website and would mean focusing more on the bot than on people. I've sprinkled keywords  here and there without spamming or making them unnatural and it's pretty annoying that they're not highlighted

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure I read something about people spamming content and making it hidden, so that may be a reason for this, but it's very bad when it affects legitimate websites. I've read about making google toggle ajax links to view data, isn't there something about clicking the links that show the hidden content to see that it's relevant? What if I make a html page for every single toggled content where it's just shown, and all the buttons or links redirect to the main page, would that help or hurt? Dummy pages that just hold the content and redirect the user to the main page.

Comment: But would the content still be on the original page?  You would be duplicate content if so, which would be an issue too.